# « Tu fais un copier-coller » ou bien « Tu copies-colles » ?

Tags: anglais, usage, conjugaison, néologismes, informatique

Dernièrement en essayant d'expliquer à mes parents comment faire un *copy/paste* sur leur PC, je me suis trouvé assez confus sur la façon d'exprimer cette notion.

Bien sûr ils ne comprennent pas l'anglais, donc pas question de parler de *copy/paste*, mais lorsque je traduis ça en français je trouve ça peu naturel.

Mon premier réflexe était de dire « Tu fais un copier-coller de ce fichier », dans le même sens que « aller-retour ». Déjà à ce point j'ai un doute si en écrivant ça donnerait *copier-coller* ou *copié-collé*, qu'en pensez-vous ?

Mais je pense aussi que comme *copier* et *coller* sont des verbes, cela devrait être conjugué dans ce contexte, ce qui donnerais « Tu copies-colles ce fichier », mais je trouve ça encore moins naturel.

C'est sans doute dû au fait que j'ai toujours utilisé *copy/paste* et que je vis dans un pays anglophone, mais j'aimerais savoir quel est l'usage recommandé dans ce contexte.

Comment: Je pense que personne n'a eu le temps de recommander quoi que ce soit. Si un courageux a envie de faire un ngram…

Comment: @Evpok : ngram me dit 0 sur toute la ligne, sauf pour « *copier et coller* ». Trop récent, je pense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pour ce qui est du nom, mon *Robert* 2007 le donne comme invariable, avec l'orthographe « copier-coller ».

Pour ce qui est du verbe, je ne crois pas qu'aucune construction du genre aie jamais existé auparavant en français. Perso, mon instinct me pousse à traiter *copier-coller* comme l'infinitif, mais à le conjuguer comme si la racine était *copie-coll-* (cf. "Je copie-collerais ça ici.").

Comme le verbe est encore rarement employé dans des temps où la première partie varierait si elle était conjuguée, ce n'est pas facile de distinguer ce qui se fait à l'écrit (je ne trouve que quelque exemples isolés sur Google Books). La première partie est parfois conjuguée, mais seulement si cela n'est pas audible (e.g. 3ème personne du pluriel). Je le trouve aussi écrit « copier/coller », mais c'est probablement un anglicisme.

Comment: +1 pour la conjugaison aussi comme *copie-coll-*, qui me semble très naturelle (phonétiquement, je crois, mais ça compte beaucoup, tout de même). (Et que j'emploie, à l'oral au moins.)

Comment: J'ajouterais que dans certains cas, il me semble naturel d'utiliser une conjugaison sur les deux verbes : "*J'ai copié-collé l'url*"; "*Il copiait-collait des articles wikipedia entier dans son mémoire*"; "*Tu peux tout faire en copiant-collant, ça passe*". Je ne dis pas que dans ces exemples c'est plus naturel qu'avec *copie-coll-*, mais ça ne me choquerait pas plus que ça.

Answer (score 8):

Il me semble qu'il s'agit d'une évolution de la langue consécutive à une évolution de la technique, et qu'il ne faut pas chercher à être rigoureux du point de vue d'éventuelles règles, mais qu'il faut se caler sur la pratique.

Copier/coller s'utilise en tant que verbe et en tant que nom il me semble ; c'est ainsi [qu'il est enregistré au wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/copier-coller). Mais rien n'empêche d'utiliser d'autres termes, si vous en trouvez. En informatique on utilise souvent l'idée du **transfert** pour expliquer tout ces concepts (par exemple il y a aussi *glisser-déposer*).

Wikipedia, quand le terme est fluctuant ou pas très satisfaisant, essaie d'appliquer le *principe de moindre surprise* qui veut qu'on emploie le terme le plus courant, même s'il est fautif, pour ne pas choquer ou même risquer de tromper le lecteur : voir [ici](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principe_de_moindre_surprise) pour la définition de ce principe, et [là](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aide%3aComment_r%C3%A9diger_un_bon_article#Principe_de_moindre_surprise) pour son application à wikipedia.

Le problème de l'informatique est que l'origine des termes vient d'informaticiens qui au départ n'ont aucune conscience du succès que leur trouvaille pourra avoir. Un terme extrêmement technique peut se retrouver au bout d'un certains temps dans les conversations du commun des mortels, par simple extension de l'usage de cette technique (URL, mél, SMS, etc).

Et à chaque extension, il est difficile de changer le mot lui même, car il est déjà en usage. Les seules possibilités de changement viennent de l'évolution de la langue.

Il arrive même souvent que des gens soient avides de ces termes techniques, de façon à se valoriser en tant qu'expert. Au moins, ils en accélèrent la diffusion, mais le sens du terme devient du n'importe quoi.

Aussi il me semble qu'il vaut mieux accompagner cette évolution, et donc par exemple proposer de nouvelles expressions, mais ne pas être dictatorial dans l'application.

En effet, la technique de composition, d'accolage est un des moteurs d'expression les plus puissants d'une langue.

Aussi il me semble qu'il vaut mieux... laisser-passer ?

Answer (score 4):

Je pense que *copier-coller* en un mot est surtout un nom. Je ne l'ai jamais entendu, sauf peut-être dans une conversation rapide en tant que verbe. Je ne l'utiliserais pas en tant que verbe dans un document écrit.

Ceci dit, la plupart des usages de *copier-coller* en tant que verbe peuvent se résumer à l'utilisation de *copier*, le collage étant implicite (c'est-à-dire qu'on fait une copie). L'utilisation de l'expression *copier-coller* est très spécifique quant à la méthode.

« Tu fais un copier-coller de ce fichier » n'est pas étrange. « Tu copies-colles ce fichier » l'est plus.

L'action peut aussi être simplifiée en disant « Tu copies ce fichier » et, si besoin, « Tu copies ce fichier par copier-coller ».

Même si c'est un peu plus long, ça n'est pas bizarre en Français : il y a en général moins de constructions qui accumulent plusieurs verbes en un seul.

De la même manière, certaines expressions en Anglais ne se traduiraient pas en un seul mot, par exemple « *pay and display* » (parking) ou « *pay-as-you-go* » (téléphone).

Answer (score 1):

Il existe des similitudes en français, des mots composés de deux verbes. Je pense à *savoir-vivre*, *laisser-passer*, *va-et-vient*. Il existe également des mots composés d'un verbe et d'un nom, comme *porte-monnaie*, *tire-bouchon* ou encore *porte-avion*.

Dans tous les cas, ces mots sont des **noms** et doivent être considérés comme tels, non comme des verbes. On ne peut donc pas les conjuguer.

La phrase suivante est **correcte** :

> Vos laisser-passer ne vous autorisent pas à faire des va-et-vient entre les porte-avions.

La phrase suivante est **incorrecte** :

> Vos laissent-passent ne vous autorisent pas à allez-et-venez entre les portent-avion.

Selon ce schéma, *un copier-coller* (pluriel *des copier-coller*) est un nom et ne peut donc pas être conjugué.

Comment: Changing topic, your usage of "*fausse*" doesn't sound right here. "Incorrecte" would be better. "Fausse" tends to refer to the veracity of what is said, not the grammatical correctness of the sentence.

Comment: Je ne vois pas le rapport. En quoi le fait que le pluriel de *laisser-passer* se forme (à juste titre) comme celui d'un nom et pas en le mettant à la troisième personne du pluriel veut dire qu'on ne peut pas conjuguer *copier-coller* ?
Plus : *aller-et-venir* se conjugue « il va-et-vient entre les arbres ».
Les *strawman arguments* pour faire du normatif, c'est pas super.

Comment: Par ailleur, dire que *Vos laissent-passent ne vous autorisent pas à allez-et-venez entre les portent-avion.* n'a aucun sens puisque seul un nom peut être placé à cet position! La forme conjuguée est *On vous laisse passer*.

Comment: **Bruno** : *fausse* est changé. **Evpok** : *aller et venir* sont des verbes, *va-et-vient* est un nom. Il est clair que si on utilise *aller et venir*, c'est comme si on utilise *copier et coller* : *tu copies et tu colles*. **Circeus** : Effectivement, ça n'a aucun sens, c'était bien le but de la démonstration. Dans ma phrase incorrecte, je considère *des laissent-passent* comme le pluriel de *un laisser-passer*. Effectivement, c'est totalement bidon.

Comment: Again *je ne vois pas pourquoi le fait que leurs pluriels se forment comme celui des noms (ce qu'ils sont) montre que le verbe copier-coller est incorrect*.