# Pluriel de mots composés constitués de verbes à l'infinitif

Tags: verbes, pluriel, infinitif

En écrivant [ma dernière question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/tu-fais-un-copier-coller-ou-bien-tu-copies-colles), cela m'a fait penser à quelque chose : comment écrit-on le pluriel de mots composés dont un ou plusieurs constituants sont eux-mêmes des verbes à l'infinitif (dans ma question, je parlais de *aller-retour* ainsi que *copier-coller*)?

Plusieurs possibilités auxquelles je pense :

1. *des aller-retours*
2. *des allers-retours*
3. *des aller et retour*

La logique voudrait que ce soit la solution 2, mais je trouve cela totalement non-naturel à écrire, et *intuitivement* (mon intuition est souvent mauvaise...) j'aurais plutôt tendance à écrire la solution 1. Quant à la 3, je l'ai déjà entendu à l'oral, mais je ne sais pas si c'était uniquement dans le contexte du parlé.

Je ne sais pas s'il y a vraiment une différence du fait que les constituants soient eux-mêmes des verbes, mais je trouve cela plus *étrange* et *non-naturel* à écrire. Y a t-il une règle spécifique pour ces cas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En l'occurrence, *aller* est un nom variable : on peut dire *des allers*. Mon Robert 2007 n'inclut pas ce nom composé, car il le traite comme une locution plutôt qu'un seul mot. Le [Grand Dictionnaire terminologique](http://www.granddictionnaire.com) (de l'Office québécois de la langue française), inclut la note qui suit :

> Certains auteurs considèrent les locutions *aller-retour* et *aller et retour* comme invariables; toutefois, dans ces locutions, les deux noms prennent normalement la marque du pluriel au besoin. On écrira donc : *des voyages allers-retours* (ou *des voyages aller-retour*), *des allers et retours* (ou *des aller et retour*), etc.

De manière générale (cf. Grevisse 14e, §§530 et 532 a.), les verbes qui font partie d'un nom composé ne s'accordent pas. Les exceptions étant les agglutinés résultant de la réforme orthographique, comme *poussepousse*, et certains termes légaux avec un participe présent (*ayants droits*, par exemple).

Reste quelques cas limites, comme *soutien-gorge* ou *appui-tête* où il y a tendance à passer au nom homophone et à accorder les parties en conséquence, passage complété dans le cas du premier : « soutient-gorge » est inexistant, note Grevisse (quoique le pluriel reste indécis).

Answer (score -1):

Des allers-retours. Car "aller" n'est pas seulement un verbe, c'est également un nom.